# Calculating probability after some events already happened to

Tags: probability

I have a question that involves probability calculations and I need help to figure out if I'm in the right direction.

Let's say I have **N** boxes. The probability that there's a cat in a certain box is **p**. This probability is independent.

Let's say I checked 50% of the boxes and found 0 cats in any of them. I could calculate the probability for this scenario using the binomial equation.

How can I calculate the probability that in the rest 50% boxes there would be exactly **k** cats? (Again, the trials are independent).

Is it just using the binomial equation again, and muliplying by my previous result, or does something change given I already checked 50%?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#:~:text=Bayes%27%20theorem%20From%20Simple%20English%20Wikipedia%2C%20the%20free,the%20probability%20of%20that%20evidence%20given%20the%20hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

No, due to the independence. Let $X$ be the (random) number of occurrences in the first half, and $Y$ be the (random) number in the remaining half. Then $\mathbb P(X=a, Y=b)=\mathbb P(X=a)\mathbb P(Y=b)$ by the definition of independence. This is equivalent to saying that $\mathbb P(Y=b\mid X=a)=\mathbb P(Y=b)$, from the definition of conditional probability.